# Puzzle about super() method

Tags: python, super

I am trying to understand how the `super()` method works. Here is the sample code I am using:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 'A'

    def func(self):
        print('@A')
        self.n += 'A'


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 'B'

    def func(self):
        print('@B')
        self.n += 'B'


class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 'C'

    def func(self):
        print('@C')
        super().func()
        self.n += 'C'


class D(C, B):
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 'D'

    def func(self):
        print('@D')
        super().func()
        self.n += 'D'


print(D.mro())
d = D()
d.func()
print(d.n)
```

The correct output results are:

```
[<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>]
DBCD
```

What I do not understand is why there is no `A` in the output? I thought when entering Class C, there is a `super().func()` which calls the `func` in Class A. However, it is not the case.

Can anyone help me understand this behavior?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, each `super().func()` call lets you call `func` in *the next class in the MRO* of `self` (which may not be the same as the MRO of the current class). When you call `C.func` on an instance of `D`, you follow `D`'s MRO and see that after `C` comes `B`.

`B.func` doesn't call `super`, so the chain ends there, skipping `A`. If you want `B.func` to be useable in multiple inheritance situations, it needs to call `super().func()` too, like the other classes do.

Answer (score 1):

`super().func` isn’t the parent’s `func` method – it’s the method of the next class in the MRO. No `A` appears because `B`’s `func` does not call `super().func`, so the chain stops at `B`.

Answer (score 0):

`super` doesn't just call the parent class.  It ensures that the classes in a multiple inheritance tree are called in the proper order.

In your case, the `super` in D calls C.  The `super` in C calls B, but because B doesn't have a call to `super`, the chain breaks down.